# Testing in nuxt 3 (vitest/jest)

Tags: jestjs, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, vitest

I have a nuxt 3.2.3 app and i want to test it. Nuxt is supporting both Jest and Vitest for testing, but i read somewhere that Vitest is the recommended one.

On the other hand `@nuxt/test-utils`  package which should be used as well already using Jest, so why should i add Vitest on top of that?

But as i know the default boundler is Vite now in nuxt3, so im pretty confused.

Which one should be used or what's are the pros/cons for each one

What's the best practice here or what are you guys using?

Comment: Okay, it turned out test-utils does not use Jest anymore but Vitest the docs are just not relevant (https://test-utils.nuxtjs.org/ guess it was for v2).

Comment: Do you have a working test environment for nuxt which is more complex than the simple examples with $fetch from the docs? And if so: are you willing to share it? I have a lot of problems. I am mostly interested in mounting components. I am using vuetify and vitest is not able to mount my components because it cannot find the ones from vuetify. Even the nuxt module i18n does not work.

Comment: Will have to work on a projekt with vuetify in the next week or so, will inform you if i can figure it out, but sounds as a bad omen. Yes btw, it is pretty problematic to test components, and u also have to import nearly everything manually, coz maybe nuxt 3 auto imports, but vitest does not... Im using `@vue/test-utils` for mounting the component in tests, but i guess you already know that.

Comment: I know @vue/test-utils. They do not work for vuetify. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest/issues/128). It's about i18n but rumors there tell vuetify isn't properly "created" in test suits.

Comment: Yep, this is a nightmare, spent hours to find out how to set a vuetify input value from tests, without success... Best result is an `Cannot call setValue on an empty VueWrapper.` error, also just as u said, vuetify elements like <v-form>  cant be resolved

Comment: We decided to do unit tests only until someone accidentally finds a solution. Later Cypress is used for integration and e2e. We are thrilled to discover what darkness lies there.

Comment: Bit late but still an option maybe: You could try/check out [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/). A collegue of mine told me said testing problems doesn't exist there. He also would never ever do a nuxt project again, if he could do it with Quasar.